# Is LVM partition order important

Tags: linux, lvm

Is the order of the partition created by the LVM important?
Because the LVM reorders the partitions

Should root or var partition, or partition with high I/O, placed at the beggining of the list?

Does this ensure that will be placed at the beggining of the disk?

Thank you

Comment: There is the very old "put swap at the beginning of the disk its faster" advise out there. I do not know if it ever was true, but with modern disks you won't notice any difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of questions and assumptions packed together here. I'll take them one at a time.

### LVM does not reorder partitions

In LVM, partitions (physical volumes in LVM parlance) are chunked into PE's (physical extends). LV's (logical volumes) are allocated across the available PE's. LVM leaves your partitions are they are, but you can move LVs around throughout your PE's in the same VG (volume group).

In fact, LVM doesn't even create partitions (it creates logical volumes). You have to create partitions first and them mark them as PV's with `pvcreate` so that LVM can use them.

### Partition location vs I/O performance

> Should root or var partition, or partition with high I/O, placed at
>   the beggining of the list?

Well... maybe. It depends on the disk. For example, I have an old USB drive which gets faster I/O earlier in the disk and progressively slows down the farther you read from the beginning. But that doesn't mean every disk has the same behaviour.

### Logical volume allocation policy

What can definitely have an impact on I/O performance is how a logical volume is allocated into PE's. The allocation policy determines which PE's are used to contain the data for an LV. If the chosen PE's are scattered about throughout the disk, then when you access the filesystem on the LV the reads may be just as scattered.

If you want the PE's for a given LV to be next to each other, then consider the contiguous allocation policy. By using contiguous allocation and creating the LV's in the order you want them, you'd essentially be forcing the LV's to be allocated in the order you want. If your chosen PV is at the beginning of the disk, and it's empty, then that's where PE allocation will begin.

You can control the allocation policy when creating LV's, which you can read about in the `lvcreate` man page.

Comment: I have only 1 logical volume using one group of 2 physical volumes. How to tell LVM to use specific PV first until all space is used and only after that write to 2nd PV? Is it doable? Can order of PVs be specified?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for but if you're trying to create LVs then you can either do this from the installer, which will create the volume and prompt you to create a VG. Or use `pvcreate /dev/sdx`, `vgcreate vgname /dev/sdx` and then use `lvcreate -n name -L sizeG/M/K` I do not think the order makes a difference, and usually `/` or `/boot` will be your first partition anyway.